# How do I open up a YAML Form in a bootstrap modal window

Tags: theming, 8

I have a form made in the YAML Form module and I would like it to open up in a bootstrap modal window.

Can I just put the Bootstrap html into my page.hmtl.twig file and print out the form somehow?

This would be sufficient for my purposes as I want to form to be accessible from all pages on the website.

If this is not the Drupal way could someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The drupal way to do this would be to use blocks. The YAML Form module has the feature to put form in blocks. Place the form block in a region, where you want to have it on the page. Then style it in a block template:

**block--my-form.html.twig**

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ content }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```